# Strength of Hash obtained by XOR of parts of SHA3

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, sha-3, keccak

I create a hash with SHA3-384. I split the resulting array into two. The first called head has the first 320 bits and the second called tail  has the last 64 bits.

Next, I XOR  head and tail. Which in fact means I XOR the last 64 bits of head with tail. This gives me a new hash of length 320.

The question is how is this resulting hash in terms of collision resistance compared to SHA-256 on one side and SHA-384 on the other side.

My goal is to produce a 320-bits hash. Is there a better way you would go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Truncating a hash *does reduce* the collision resistance. Mixing in an independent string *does not*.

$$
\text{random thing} \oplus \text{independent thing} \to \text{random thing}\\
\text{random thing} \oplus \text{independent random thing} \to \text{random thing}
$$

Truncating hashes is common and the reduction is relative to the bits lost. The truncated $\text{sha3}_{384[320]}$ *should* be stronger than $\text{sha2}_{256}$ and *is* weaker than $\text{sha3}_{384}$.

I recommend that you do not try to mix in the truncated $64$-bits.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up extending  KeccakDisgest class from Bouncycastle to overwrite the init() method so i can pass my length directly. It works like a charm.